# can visualsvn server be bound to more then one port?

Tags: port, visualsvn-server

I know i can go to the visualsvn server properties and specify the port and IP address. But what i would like to know is if i can specify a different port for different IP addresses?

For example, say i have ip address x.x.x.x and port 8443

when i add a 2nd IP of y.y.y.y, it also bound to port 8443. If i change the port to 1234, it looks like it also changes the port on the first IP as well. Any way to set the port for a specific IP address?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add following Apache directives to "%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\conf\httpd-custom.conf" to bind VisualSVN Server on different IP address and port:

```
Listen 1.2.3.4:81
Listen 10.20.30.40:82
```

Please do not edit **httpd.conf** for VisualSVN Server customization, use **httpd-custom.conf** instead.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can, although not using the GUI, which is kind of silly. I just edited the http.conf file in the visualsvn/conf folder to include the IP:PORT i wanted to bind to. Not sure why this isn't possible in the GUI as well. And i'm not sure what'll happen if i try to edit the network settings using the GUI. Hopefully it wont over-write my manual entry.

one additional step though - needed to use netsh to specifically bind IIS to IP's so that it wouldn't bind to ALL IP's and prevent visualsvn server from using one.